# Hit DB only once while filtering a queryset in Django-rest-framework

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am filtering a model under some conditions say,
`qs = Model.objects.filter(category=value)`.
I am send this queryset as a response using `ListModelMixin`.

```
class ModelViewset(ListModelmixin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model.objects.filter(category=value)
```

The select statement was running `n` times for n items which seems reduntant, Somehow I want to hit db only once and use them as Response.

I tried `list`, but it has too much overhead and has slowed down the performance.
Is there any way to acheive this by not using `list`, `bool` or remaining things as they will also execute each items which results in `n` queries for `n` items in Model.

**Update**:

Thank you [Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) for guiding to the solution.

Comment: That's not due to the queryset, but the serializer that invokes an *N+1 problem*. Please add the serializer and model.

Comment: Thank you so much for raising _N+1_ problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some foreign keys that I have not prefetched (prefetch_related or select_related) which is causing `N+1` problem.

add `.select_related(foreign_fields)` or `.prefetch_related(m2m_fields)` clause to query which will solve `N+1` problem.

In my case:

`return Model.objects.filter(category=value).select_related(*foreign_key_fields)`

solved my problem.

reference: [N+1 Queries in Django](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/n-1-queries-in-django-how-they-affect-performance-and-how-to-fix-and-find-them-8123f1500aae#:%7E:text=The%20N%2B1%20query%20problem,result%20of%20the%20original%20query.)